# How to remove basic-error-controller in Open Api (swagger)

Tags: configuration, swagger, openapi

I`m trying to migrate swagger2 to openApi but following the official steps i have the basic-error-controller in my swagger. The configuration i scan to try it is this:

```
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi publicApi() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .setGroup("springshop-public")
            .addOpenApiCustomiser(this.consumerTypeHeaderOpenAPICustomiser())
            .pathsToExclude("/error")
            .build();
}

private GroupedOpenApi adminApi() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .setGroup("springshop-admin")
            .pathsToExclude("/error")
            .build();
}
```

But it is not working. Some help? Remeber is OpenApi.

Comment: Rather than saying. "it is not working,"  share what's happening vs. what you expect to happen.  For example, are there any errors?  https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/#problem-statement

Comment: There is no errors, i just want to remove the /basic-error-controller from the endpoints that the swagger shows